# Error in exporting json file with one query from mongoexport

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongoexport

everyone I'm trying to export query in csv format from cmd with mongoexport. I wrote the following line:

```
mongoexport --db=wine --collection=review --type=json --fields=_id,points,title,description,taster_name,taster_twiter_handle,price,designation,variety,region_1,region_2,province,country,winery --query="{'taster_name':{exists:true}}" --out=review_cleaned.csv
```

I think that is correct but I'm obtaining this error:

```
2021-12-08T17:02:36.695+0100    connected to: mongodb://localhost/
2021-12-08T17:02:36.760+0100    Failed: error parsing query as Extended JSON: invalid JSON input
```

What am I wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: output json not csv sorry

Answer (score 0):

You must escape the double quotes on the query with a backslash:

```
mongoexport --db=wine --collection=review --type=json --fields=_id,points,title,description,taster_name,taster_twiter_handle,price,designation,variety,region_1,region_2,province,country,winery --query=\"{'taster_name':{exists:true}}\" --out=review_cleaned.csv
```